# How to make an inline <ul> stretch full width of container

Tags: html, css

My HTML

```
<div id="main_navigation">
    <ul><li><a href="/One">One</li></a><li><a href="/Two">Two</li></a><li><a href="/three">Three</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#main_navigation ul {
margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#main_navigation ul li {
display: inline;
font-size:24px;
}

#main_navigation ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #cbc19e;
background-color: #322918;
}

#main_navigation ul li a:hover {
color: #322918;
background-color: #cbc19e;
}
```

This looks perfect EXCEPT it does not quite stretch out to the full width of the rest of the objects on the page.  The container has:

```
margin:0 50px 0 50px;
```

as do all of the other containers on the page.   The only one that does not stretch the full width is the nav bar.  I would not like to use tables or jscript if possible.  Suggestions?

Comment: would you provide the image  you want to do.

Comment: so what exactly do you want give a idea....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#main_navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:24px;
}

#main_navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .2em 1em;
  color: #cbc19e;
  background-color: #322918;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

Change the `display` attribute to `inline-block` and `block` respectively, and set `width` to whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you!  This one does not solve my issue exactly, but it does present an acceptable alternative.  The navbar still does not stretch the full width of the div, but now the bar is responsive (it was before but it looks nice now).  I will be implementing this suggestion today.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#main_navigation ul 
    {display:table;
    width:100%;}
#main_navigation ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table-cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just have to apply `display: block`, `float: left` and `width: 33.3%` on `<li>` elements to make them stretch out the full width of the `<ul>` element, which is already at 100% of the containing `<div>`.

See how it works in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bnj9v/).

The code is as follows:

```
#container {
    margin:0 50px 0 50px;
}

#main_navigation ul {
    margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: cyan;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main_navigation ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size:24px;
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}

#main_navigation ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #cbc19e;
    background-color: #322918;
}

#main_navigation ul li a:hover {
    color: #322918;
    background-color: #cbc19e;
}
```

Note that there are mistakes in the links within your HTML code,

It should be:

```
 <div id="main_navigation">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="/One">One</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Two">Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="/three">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: adding display: block; when float: left; is declared is not necessary as float triggers display: block; automatically (and hasLayout for old IE)

Comment: 1.)This solution does stretch the menu out, so good there.  Unfortunately it also pulls the menu items apart so there is now space between them.
2.)Regarding the HTML correction posted above:  If you are pointing out the fact that I wrote that block on one line, it is to keep space from appearing between the navbar blocks.  Putting it all on one line makes them connect to each other.

Comment: Actually, he was referring to the fact that you're closing your tags in the wrong order - you have this:
`<li><a>something</li></a>`
When it should be
`<li><a>something</a></li>`